# Jquery - Validator error Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to validate a form using jquery's validate function. When I trigger the .valid() function, I get a 'Cannot read property call of undefined.

```
<script>
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        EditSubName: {
            required: true, 
        }, 
        EditSubStreetNumber: {
            required: true, 
        },
        EditSubStreetName: {
            required: true  
        },
        EditSubSuburb: {
            required: true, 
        },
        EditSubState: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true,  
        },
        EditSubPostcode: {
            required: true, 
        },
        EditSubEmail: {
            email: true,    
        }
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
         return true;
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest("input")
        .addClass("textbox_001_err")
        .removeClass("textbox_001");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest("input")
        .removeClass("textbox_001_err")
        .addClass("textbox_001");
    },  
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('Submitting Entered');
        //Update only
            if($("#radiono").prop("checked") == true)
            {
                alert('Entered Radio No');
                  $(".blackout").css("display", "none");
                   $.ajax({
                    url: 'save/saveSubjectonly.asp',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        SubjectID: $('#DefSubID').val(),
                        name: $('#EditSubName').val(),
                        dob: $('#EditSubDOB').val(),
                        email: $('#EditSubEmail').val() ,
                        telephone: $('#EditSubTelephone').val() ,
                        mobile: $('#EditSubMobile').val() ,
                        fax: $('#EditSubFax').val() ,
                        streetnumber: $('#EditSubStreetNumber').val() ,
                        streetname: $('#EditSubStreetName').val() ,
                        suburb: $('#EditSubSuburb').val() ,
                        postcode: $('#EditSubPostcode').val() ,
                        state: $('#EditSubState').val() ,
                        notes: $('#EditSubjectNotes').val(),
                        activalue: $('input:checkbox:checked').val(),
                        companyname: $('#EditCompanyName').val()
                    },
                    success: function(result){

                            //location.reload()

                    }
                });

            }; 
            //Made changes for all
            if($("#radioyes").prop("checked") == true)
            {
                    $(".blackout").css("display", "none");
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'save/saveSubjectandupdate.asp',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        SubjectID: $('#DefSubID').val(),
                        name: $('#EditSubName').val(),
                        dob: $('#EditSubDOB').val(),
                        email: $('#EditSubEmail').val() ,
                        telephone: $('#EditSubTelephone').val() ,
                        mobile: $('#EditSubMobile').val() ,
                        fax: $('#EditSubFax').val() ,
                        streetnumber: $('#EditSubStreetNumber').val() ,
                        streetname: $('#EditSubStreetName').val() ,
                        suburb: $('#EditSubSuburb').val() ,
                        postcode: $('#EditSubPostcode').val() ,
                        state: $('#EditSubState').val() ,
                        notes: $('#EditSubjectNotes').val(),
                        activalue: $('input:checkbox:checked').val(),
                        companyname: $('#EditCompanyName').val()
                    },
                    success: function(result){
                            alert('Success');
                            //location.reload()

                    }
                });
            } 
    },
});
</script>
```

I am not sure as to why this is happening. I know that it does not go into the SubmitHandler because none of the alert message trigger.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. What I had forgotten is that the lettersonly in the EditSubState rule is part of the additional-methods.js which was not included in the page.

Once I have included that, the validation works without a problem.

Comment: I had the same error when trying to use the 'require_from_group' rule without including 'additional/require_from_group.js'.

Answer (score 0):

You've got trailing commas in your validation attributes within rules object.

```
    rules: {
        EditSubName: {
            required: true
        }, 
        EditSubStreetNumber: {
            required: true 
        },
        EditSubStreetName: {
            required: true  
        },
        EditSubSuburb: {
            required: true
        },
        EditSubState: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true
        },
        EditSubPostcode: {
            required: true
        },
        EditSubEmail: {
            email: true 
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this library for jquery, but for the docs, I think you are missing one parameter for each one of your functions or "methods".

For the docs the highlight function must be defined as follows:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).fadeOut(function() {
      $(element).fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

I think JS is trying to call that specific signature, but there are no functions defined for that, so there you have the undefined.

Here are the docs: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Also, the commas that mention Papa are wrong.